# In Rails, how to implement a WYSIWYG editor for users to create snail-mail form letters (with template tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editor, wysiwyg, templatetags

I see a lot of questions here dealing with WYSIWYG editors, etc. but haven't found a solution to what I need to accomplish. I have a Rails 3.2 app with some client information. We are sending some snail-mail form letters and other printed documents to individuals. Currently we are using Word with a mail merge, but I would like to build this functionality into the app.

I would like to give admins the ability to create a new form letter (or other document with relatively simple formatting). Their editor would also provide some preset template tags to use within the letter. Something like the following in their document creation editor:

```
%%person.address.street%%
%%person.address.city%%, %%person.address.state%% %%person.address.zip_code%%

%%current_date%%

Dear %%person.first_name%%, 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque iaculis felis
nec quam elementum sit amet laoreet sapien feugiat. Cras tincidunt dignissim
eleifend. Integer hendrerit turpis at odio mollis eget ultricies est dictum.
Donec feugiat turpis eget enim lacinia suscipit...

Sincerely,

%%user.first_name%% %%user.last_name%%
```

Admins could save this document template as something like "Welcome Letter." Then while viewing a Person record, there would be an option to "Generate Welcome Letter."

Is there a good solution for creating a document editor for admins that also allows for the use of such template tags?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a template markup language such as [liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/), or [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). The hard part seems to be making the UI for the editor friendly enough for non-technical people to use.